# Cannot install pymssql from wheel format

Tags: python, pymssql, python-wheel

I want to install pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
but when run the following code :

```
C:\Users\----\Downloads>c:/python/python35-32/scripts/pip install "pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
```

the response of pip install is:

> pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
>   this platform.

my python is 3.5 (os: windown 10 64bit)

Comment: I removed  ` (1)` and checked again. but the error is exist. my pip version is 8.0.2

Comment: It looks like you are using 32-bit Python. Use the 32 bit wheel named pymssql-2.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl